# How do I make a walking and running sound?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, audio

I have the sounds, and I have done so when I hold <kbd>w</kbd> it starts the walking sound and when released stops.
But when I have done <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>collision</kbd> the run sound overlaps the walking sound:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want the "walk-sound" to stop at collision?

Answer (score 0):

Add another keyboard Sensor L-shift but make it inverted, connect that to the left side of the Controller linked to your walk sound Actuator but make sure its only W and the inverted L-shift sensors connected, that should keep the run sound but stop the walk sound if L-shift is pressed